# Foreign key as primary key annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, primary-key

There is 2 entity
Product(product_id(PK),product_name..)
Store(product_id(PK,FK),product_quantity,...)

I need @OneToOne, so i do this

```
public class Product{
  @Id
  @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
  @OneToOne(mappedBy="product")
  private int product_id;
  ....
}

public class Store{
  @Id
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
  private Product product;
}
```

Compilier says @Column(s) not allowed on a @OneToOne property: ......shopdb.entity.Product.product_id

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I just moved @OneToOne(mappedBy="product") to new created field in Product

private Store store;

I dont understand how it works correct;
Why i need to use 3 fields instead of 2?

Comment: You have figured out the correct way to map these relationships. The `@OneToOne(mappedBy="product")` annotation on `Product.store` tells JPA that the `store` field does not map to a column in the `PRODUCT`, as its value is determined by `Store.product`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mark a column defined with `@JoinColumn` as `@Id`. This is applicable only to columns defined with `@Column` annotation.

It is also a bit strange what are you trying to do. You are basically making the `produc_id` primary key for both entites, so then why don't make just one?

From what I can see here, I believe that the `Store` should have a store id property which will be used as primary key.

Comment: Yes, i tried this.

Now Product remains the same and i change Store, now i apply OneToOne and JoinColumn on Product product, while i have store_id as Id

Anyway i have an error:Column(s) not allowed on a OneToOne property
I cant use Column and OneToOne together

Comment: @АнтонШибанов That is what I said. It is wrong that you try to make a primary key the product. You should re-think the model. Store id is the correct primary key.